# Using Distinct in SQL Update

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update, distinct

Here is the Select I need to convert to an Update:

```
SELECT DISTINCT f.SectionID, f.Name, v.Enabled
FROM SETTING_VALUE v
INNER JOIN SETTING s ON v.SettingID = s.SettingID
INNER JOIN LU_FIELD f ON f.FieldID = s.FieldID
WHERE v.DisplayValue LIKE '%Miami%'
AND f.ControlName LIKE '%City%'
```

My attempt:

```
UPDATE SETTING_VALUE
SET Enabled = 0
FROM SETTING_VALUE v
INNER JOIN SETTING s ON v.SettingID = s.SettingID
INNER JOIN LU_FIELD f ON f.FieldID = s.FieldID
WHERE v.DisplayValue LIKE '%Miami%'
AND f.ControlName LIKE '%City%'
```

Not sure how to apply Distinct

Comment: What do you mean by `update distinct`?  Can you show us the data before and after the update?

Comment: Good work using a `SELECT` to view the data before you update it. I don't know why you'd want to use a `DISTINCT` projection, though. Shouldn't all of the matching rows be updated? I'm not seeing how `DISTINCT` would make sense logically.

Comment: Yes, SQL Server. Yes, all of the matching rows should be updated. It's just setting a bit from 1 to 0. Maybe I don't need DISTINCT.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Based on your comment, `all of the matching rows should be updated` you don't need distinct.  Just execute this:

```
UPDATE SETTING_VALUE
SET Enabled = 0
FROM SETTING_VALUE v
INNER JOIN SETTING s ON v.SettingID = s.SettingID
INNER JOIN LU_FIELD f ON f.FieldID = s.FieldID
WHERE v.DisplayValue LIKE '%Miami%'
AND f.ControlName LIKE '%City%'
```

Everything that you saw in your select will be updated.

Answer (score 2):

Option 1: Use a temporary table to hold your initial query results, then update based on the query results.

Option 2:

```
Insert into SETTING_VALUE
(SectionID, Name, Enabled)
SELECT DISTINCT f.SectionID, f.Name, v.Enabled
FROM SETTING_VALUE v
INNER JOIN SETTING s ON v.SettingID = s.SettingID
INNER JOIN LU_FIELD f ON f.FieldID = s.FieldID
WHERE v.DisplayValue LIKE '%Miami%'
AND f.ControlName LIKE '%City%'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE SETTING_VALUE
   SET Enabled = 0
 WHERE DisplayValue LIKE '%Miami%'
       AND EXISTS (
                   SELECT *
                     FROM SETTING s 
                    WHERE SETTING_VALUE.SettingID = s.SettingID
                          AND EXISTS (
                                      SELECT *
                                        FROM LU_FIELD f 
                                       WHERE f.FieldID = s.FieldID
                                             AND f.ControlName LIKE '%City%'
                                     )
                  );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following

```
UPDATE v
SET Enabled = 0 
FROM SETTING_VALUE v 
WHERE EXISTS(
   select * from SETTING s 
   INNER JOIN LU_FIELD f ON f.FieldID = s.FieldID 
   WHERE v.DisplayValue LIKE '%Miami%' 
   AND f.ControlName LIKE '%City%' 
   AND v.SettingID = s.SettingID
)
```